# Finding a optimal mixed strategy for a 4x4 matrix

Tags: game-theory

Determine the optimal mixed strategy for player 1 given

A = 0. 2. 1. -1
3. 4. 0  -5
-1. 3  0.  2
-2. -1 2.  1

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: \begin{bmatrix}0&2&1&-1\\3&4&0&-5\\-1&3&0&2\\-2&-1&2&1\end{bmatrix}

Comment: im not really sure where to start other than the probabilities p1 +p2+ p3 +p4 =1

Comment: Have you calculated the expected value of each choice?

Comment: no? I have never heard of that

Comment: I have got the following equations

Comment: v>= 3p2 -p3 -2p4

Comment: v>= 2p1 +4p2+3p3-p4

Comment: v>= p1 +2p4  and

Comment: v>= -p1 -5p2 +2p3 +p4